# INSERT SPARK DATAFRAME INTO HIVE Managed Acid Table not working, HDP 3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a issue with inserting the Spark dataframe into hive table. Can anyone please help me out. HDP version 3.1, Spark version 2.3 Thanks in advance.

//ORIGNAL CODE PART

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseSessionImpl;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$;

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
**val hive = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(spark).build()**
/*
Some Transformation operations happend and the output of transformation is stored in VAL RESULT
/*
val result = {
  num_records
  .union(df.transform(profile(heatmap_cols2type)))
}

result.createOrReplaceTempView("out_temp"); //Create tempview

scala> result.show()
+-----+--------------------+-----------+------------------+------------+-------------------+
| type|              column|      field|             value|       order|               date|
+-----+--------------------+-----------+------------------+------------+-------------------+
|TOTAL|                 all|num_records|               737|           0|2019-12-05 18:10:12|
|  NUM|available_points_...|    present|               737|           0|2019-12-05 18:10:12|

hive.setDatabase("EXAMPLE_DB")
hive.createTable("EXAMPLE_TABLE").ifNotExists().column("`type`", "String").column("`column`", "String").column("`field`", "String").column("`value`","String").column("`order`", "bigint").column("`date`", "TIMESTAMP").create()

hive.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE EXAMPLE_DB.EXAMPLE_TABLE SELECT * FROM out_temp");

-----ERROR of Orginal code----------------
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:86 Table not found 'out_temp'**strong text**
```

**What I tried as a alternative is: (As Hive and Spark use independent catalogues, by checking the documentation from HWC write operations)**

spark.sql("SELECT type, column, field, value, order, date FROM out_temp").write.format("HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR").option("table", "wellington_profile").save()

**-------ERROR of Alternative Step----------------
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:241)
  ... 58 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HiveWarehouseSession.HIVE_WAREHOUSE_CONNECTOR.DefaultSource**

My Question is:

Instead of saving the out_temp as a tempview in Spark is there any way to directly create the table in hive ?
Is there any way to insert into Hive table from spark dataframe ?

Thank you everyone for your time!

Answer (score 0):

result.write.save("example_table.parquet")

Answer (score 0):

```
result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("EXAMPLE_TABLE")
```

You can read in more detail from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html)

Comment: I tried the result.write but below is the error:
scala> result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("EXAMPLE_DB"."EXAMPLE_TABLE")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'dfa60358_wellington_fz_db' not found;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.scala:177)
The EXAMPLE_TABLE is created using HIVE Catalog. 
Is there anyway to to INSERT into hive table from the Spark DF?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Comment: I tried this method below:
result.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector").option("database", "EXAMPLE_DB").option("table", "EXAMPLE_TABLE").mode("Append").save()
Justification: As the dataframe "result" is in Spark catalog we cannot insert to Hive Catalog. We need to use Hadoop 3.0 Write operation HiveWareHouseConnector. 
But the issue is the "result" dataframe is stored as DELTA files in Hive table HDFS location "EXAMPLE_TABLE". 
Whereas in HDP 2.6 we can do DF insert to HIVE table using Spark.SQL which will create part files in Table HDFS location

Comment: @Venka How did you resolved this issue.I'm also getting the same issue.

Comment: You need to use HiveWarehouseConnector to save your Spark DF. result.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector").option("database", "EXAMPLE_DB").option("table", "EXAMPLE_TABLE").mode("Append").save()